# JavaScript Linking Select Options to Snippets of Code

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to JavaScript, so please be patient. I've searched online the last few days looking for a solution, but I'm not finding one.  A big reason for that is I don't really know what I'm supposed to be looking for.

With that being said, **help with code would be great.  If you don't care to write any code in response, but would be willing to point me in the right direction as to what would be a solution for my problem, that would be fantastic as well.**

What I'm trying to do:  User chooses an option from the second dropdown box which then displays the 'SHOW ME WHERE TO GO' button.  When the button is clicked, a div is displayed over the top with a video embedded in it to provide them directions.

My problem:  I feel like I need an array or object of some kind to link select options to snippets of embed code for dropping into the directions_container div.  **I don't know how to link options selected by the user to the appropriate code snippets.**  Clicking the SHOW ME WHERE TO GO button should trigger the appropriate snippet of code to be inserted into the div tag.

Below is my current project code.

HTML

```
<div id="directions_container">
<p id="embed"></p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span href="" onclick="close_div()">Choose New Directions</span>
</div>
<div id="SelectionBoxes">
<select id="TransactionType" onchange="check();">
<option selected="selected" value="">I am a...</option> 
<option value="DH">Drop and Hook</option>
 <option value="Live">Live Unload</option>
 <option value="LTL">LTL</option>
  <option value="FedEx">FedEx Ground/Express</option>
   <option value="Visitor">Visitor</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="DHOps" style=display:none; onchange="showbtn();">
<option selected="selected" value="">Describe your transaction...</option>
    <option value="LILO">Load In - Load Out</option>
    <option value="LIEO">Load In - Empty Out</option>
    <option value="EILO">Empty In - Load Out</option>
    <option value="EIEO">Empty In - Empty Out</option>
    <option value="BILO">Bobtail In - Load Out</option>
    <option value="PUP">Pup Trailers/Containers</option>
    <option value="CONT">Containers</option>
</select>
<select id="LUOps" style=display:none; onchange="showbtn();">
<option selected="selected" value="">Where will you be unloaded?</option>
    <option value="WH1">Warehouse 1 / 100 Level Docks</option>
    <option value="WH2">Warehouse 2 / 200 Level Docks</option>
    <option value="WH3">Warehouse 3 / 300 Level Docks</option>
    <option value="WH4">Warehouse 4 / 400 Level Docks</option>
</select>
<select id="LTLOps" style=display:none; onchange="showbtn();">
<option selected="selected" value="">Where do I go?</option>
    <option value="327">Dock Door 327</option>
</select>
<select id="FEDEXOps" style=display:none; onchange="showbtn();">
<option selected="selected" value="">Describe your transaction...</option>
    <option value="RETURNS">Returns Load In - Load Out</option>
    <option value="EMPTY">Empty In - Load Out</option>
</select>
<select id="VISITOROps" style=display:none; onchange="showbtn();">
<option selected="selected" value="">What is the purpose of your visit?</option>
    <option value="MAINT">Delivery for Maintenance</option>
    <option value="VEND">Canteen/Vending</option>
    <option value="GARBAGE">Garbage Pickup</option>
    <option value="OFFICE">Visit Transportation Office</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button id="submit" type="button" style=display:none; onclick="provideDirections();">SHOW ME WHERE TO GO</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#directions_container {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function check() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("TransactionType");
    var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    if (current_value == "DH") {
        document.getElementById("DHOps").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("LUOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LTLOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FEDEXOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("VISITOROps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (current_value == "Live") {
        document.getElementById("LUOps").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("DHOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LTLOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FEDEXOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("VISITOROps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (current_value == "LTL") {
        document.getElementById("LTLOps").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("DHOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LUOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FEDEXOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("VISITOROps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (current_value == "FedEx") {
        document.getElementById("FEDEXOps").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("DHOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LUOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LTLOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("VISITOROps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
    if (current_value == "Visitor") {
        document.getElementById("VISITOROps").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("DHOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LUOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("LTLOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("FEDEXOps").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function showbtn() {
  var childboxes = [
    document.getElementById("DHOps"),
    document.getElementById("LUOps"),
    document.getElementById("LTLOps"),
    document.getElementById("FEDEXOps"),
    document.getElementById("VISITOROps"),
  ];

  childboxes.forEach((childbox) => {
    if (childbox.onchange) {
      document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block";
      
    }
  });
}

function provideDirections() {
var embed_directions = {}
  document.getElementById("directions_container").style.display = "block";
  

}

function close_div () {
document.getElementById("directions_container").style.display = "none";

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are repeating the same code for every `current_value`, why is this?

Comment: I'm just learning code.  While others may know how to cut down on a lot of code to have the same result, I'm simply going through and trying to make things work for each spot of functionality in ways I know how to based on what I've learned.  To me, understanding things is still very murky and that's why I'm doing a project to better understand.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the problem. Capture the selected values, insert them into an array as objects and work with them. let optionSelected= []; optionSelected.push({TransactionType: dropdown.value});

Comment: What's confusing me is I have several dropdown boxes (DHOps, LUOps, LTLOps, FEDEXOps, and VISITOROps) with multiple options for each box.  If it was one set of options, it would be a little more straight forward.  Again, I'm just learning this stuff.  I appreciate the direction though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea to have the data about what to select in an array/object.

I guess there are a lot of new stuff here, but notice especially that the data item is inserted into the option element as `itemdata`. This is a trick for passing around data.

```js
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    title: "Option 1",
    suboptions: [{
      id: "1a",
      title: "Option 1a"
    }, {
      id: "1b",
      title: "Option 1b"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Option 2",
    suboptions: [{
      id: "2a",
      title: "Option 2a"
    }, {
      id: "2b",
      title: "Option 2b"
    }]
  }
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.forms.selection.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.first.value,e.target.second.value, "was selected")
  });
  
  document.forms.selection.second.addEventListener('change', e => {
    document.forms.selection.button.disabled = false;
  });

  document.forms.selection.first.addEventListener('change', e => {
    let optVal = e.target.value;
    let optElm = e.target.querySelector(`option[value = '${optVal}']`);
    if (optElm){
      update(optElm.itemdata.suboptions, document.forms.selection.second);
    } else {
      document.forms.selection.second.innderHTML = '';
      document.forms.selection.second.disabled = true;
      document.forms.selection.button.disabled = true;
    }
  });
  update(data, document.forms.selection.first);
});

const update = (array, select) => {
  select.innerHTML = '';
  let opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
  select.appendChild(opt);
  array.forEach(item => {
    let opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
    opt.value = item.id;
    opt.innerText = item.title;
    opt.itemdata = item;
    select.appendChild(opt);
  });
  select.disabled = false;
};
```

```html
<form name="selection">
  <select name="first" required disabled>
  </select>
  <select name="second" required disabled>
  </select>
  <button name="button" disabled>Go!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, a vast improvement over what I put together!  Thank you so much for taking the time to put all that together.  I added sample embed codes as video in the data object.  I tried using some of your code as a template to add an event listener for clicking the Go button.  The intention is to insert the video embed code into the div HTML tag via the option selected from the second selection box.  It's not working which isn't surprising as this all feels over my head.  Here is the JS Fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/2ca4w860/

Comment: @bruntonomo in line 34-36 I added code for inserting the video into the directions_container div: https://jsfiddle.net/1gecboyr/

Comment: Almost perfect!  I see that if the user changes options after the video has been displayed, it will display another video.  How can we only display the video based on the option in the second box (hide the initial selection's video)?  If the user changes the selection of the first box, the video should disappear as well.  I know how to show/hide using CSS and JavaScript, but only with specific elements.

Comment: @bruntonomo OK, it is a bit hacky, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/0db28trg/ you can see that I search for the iframe and set the outHTML = "" - this will remove the iframe.

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you so much with all your help with this!  Just so you know, I have taken the time to look through the code and try to understand the inner workings.  I read it and feel like I understand what you're doing, but when it comes time for me to alter the code, I clearly don't have a good grasp on things.  I ordered several coding books that came in today.  Hopefully I can learn and develop into someone as knowledgeable as you with this stuff.  Thank you again!